# A cctv system for a small shop

Tags: physical, surveillance, cctv

I am not sure if I should ask here but I really can't find any information anywhere else.
A family member of mine (let's say X) runs a small fashion shop in Hong Kong, China. The problem is that someone stole an iphone from the shop before and X wanted to install a cctv surveillance system in the shop for further security.

Details of the shop:

Location: Hong Kong island, Hong Kong

Size: 10m x 10m

Shape of the shop: Square with the door in the middle of the front side. On the left and front side is full glass while the back and the right is wall.

X wanted to install 2 cameras, one looking at the door and one looking at the reception and the whole shop.

Edit:
Please can someone tell me what type of system model I should use(eg. Analog/IP camera) and what type of recording device and camera I should get.

Comment: Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic as they become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have already describe my situation and the problem that i am solving...

Comment: "Can someone please tell me a complete setup of a full cctv system with the name/model number of the camera and the recording machine. Possibly a monitor to have a live view of the cameras(not necessary). X only have a very low budget, around HKD$4000($515usd)." -> product recommendation

Comment: You need to discuss this with a security camera vendor or consultant. Not every answer is available on the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

If you have very low budget **and some Linux skills**, then instead of buying commercial surveillance system, I suggest you to build one yourself.

You will need:

- a few Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 cameras (35$ each, use this specific model, as it has the best handling for different light levels, which is important for motion detection)
- cheap computer (you can use eg. some HP Thin Client model, even for less than 100$)
- disk or pen drive to install operating system (4GB will be enough)
- another disk (use either Seagate Surveillance or WD Purple, not anything else) to store recorded movies (100-120$ for 1TB, which should be enough, up to 300$ for huge 6TB WD)

First, connect everything together, install and hide cameras etc. Then install Debian or Ubuntu Server. Configure "motion" daemon - you will find many examples in Google, eg.:

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/780055-how-to-operate-linux-spycams-with-motion

https://www.debian-administration.org/article/347/An_Introduction_to_Video_Surveillance_with_%27Motion%27

This should be enough minimal setup. Just be sure, that "motion" writes movies to surveillance disk, not the primary one.

Last thing: make a backup copy of primary disk/pen drive. It's probably cheap and with no RAID, so when it fails, be sure to just plug in another one.

Comment: Thanks for your recommandation. I do have some linux experience but X does not :( and I will not be with X for a long time(studing overseas). Do you know any good model of recording system?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that such system is 100% manageable remotely. It just needs to be connected to Internet. As for commercial systems, I know that QNAP and Synology make very good hardware, and very easy to use, but in both cases also very expensive.

Comment: Thanks I will consider your linux solution. Just saying but the shop X owns does not have internet connection.

Comment: @Red2awn As Lucas Kauffman said above, asking for consumer product recommendations is against the policies of this site. Do a Google search for "consumer electronics forum", you might have better responses posting on one of those sites.